# C# - Run SQL Query For Each Item In Listbox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, listbox

I have a listbox populated with items via a SQL query from an Oracle database. I would like to be able to run a separate SQL query for the value of each item in the listbox and populate a separate listbox with the returned value.

```
    string sql2 = "select unique apps.fnd_application_all_view.application_name, fnd_responsibility_vl.responsibility_name, fnd_form_functions_tl.user_function_name, fnd_form_functions.function_name, fnd_form_functions_tl.description, fnd_form_functions.type FROM fnd_compiled_menu_functions, fnd_form_functions, fnd_form_functions_tl, fnd_responsibility, fnd responsibility_vl, apps.fnd_application_all_view WHERE fnd_compiled_menu_functions.function_id = fnd_form_functions.function_id AND fnd_responsibility.menu_id = fnd_compiled_menu_functions_menu_id AND fnd_responsibility_vl.responsibility_id = fnd_responsibility.responsibility_id AND fnd_form_functions.function_id = fnd_form_functions_tl.function_id AND apps.fnd_application_all_view.application_id(+) = fnd_responsibility.application_id AND fnd_responsibility.end_date is NULL AND fnd_responsibility_vl.end_date is NULL AND source_lang = 'US' AND fnd_responsibility_vl.responsibility_name = '" + lstResponsibilities.Items + "'";



                using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql2, conn))
                {

                    lstResponsibilities.DisplayMember = "Responsibility_Name";
                    lstResponsibilities.ValueMember = "Responsibility_Name";
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Function_Name");
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        object[] objCollection = new object[lstResponsibilities.Items.Count];
                        lstResponsibilities.Items.CopyTo(objCollection, 0);
                        MessageBox.Show((objCollection[0] as DataRowView)[1] as string);
                    }
```

I would like to loop through the items ("Responsibility_Name") in lstResponsibilities and populate another listbox, lstFunctions, with the "Function_Name" selected in the query.

I know that I am doing something massively wrong - can someone help me get on the right track?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Use parameterized queries](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries).

Comment: Thanks - I have parameterized my queries and now it is working and secure.

Comment: That's good to hear! Working (and working well) code makes me happy.